# How to get correctly a file via file_get_content or curl

Tags: php, curl

I tried to download a file via Icecat. The file need an access to be downloaded.

My problem is :

- the file_get_content does'nt download the file. My directory is on 777 and the path is correct.
- if I insert the document inside the directory, the file is not unzipped.

  ```
  public function getIceCatFile() {

        set_time_limit (0);

        $url = 'https://data.Icecat.biz/export/freexml/EN/daily.index.xml.gz';

        $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array( 'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($this->username . ":" . $this->password) )));

        if ($this->checkDirectoryIceCat() === true) {

           // does'nt download the file inside the server directory    
          file_get_contents($url, true, $context);

          $file = $this->IceCatDirectory . 'daily.index.xml.gz';


          if (is_file($file)) {
            $zip = new \ZipArchive;

            // error failed same if I include the file inside the directory    
            $icecat_file = $zip->open($this->IceCatDirectory . 'files.index.xml.gz');

            if ($icecat_file === true) {
              $zip->extractTo($icecat_file);
              $zip->close();
              echo 'file downloaded and unzipped';
            } else {
              echo 'failed';
            }
          } else {
            echo 'error no file found in ' . $file;
          }
        }
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Make a try like this to download file that has **username** and **password** authentication using PHP `Curl`,

```
$localfile = fopen($file_store_locally, 'wb'); // open with write enable
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $localfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); // see here for auth
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($localfile); //store file data to local file
```